# How to retrieve native function code after it was redefined by third-party js?

Tags: javascript, promise, tumblr, userscripts

I'm writing a userscript for tumblr that makes ajax calls to its API over an array of data and I need the responses to come in the order the data was in the array. I was advised to use Promises for that as the article shows (http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/#toc-parallelism-sequencing).

It works on individual tumblr blog pages, but not on the dashboard, where native implementation of Promise is overwritten by their [index.js](https://secure.assets.tumblr.com/client/prod/app/vendor/index.js). As the result, their Promise lacks .resolve() ability and my code doesn't work.

Can I still find a way to use the native Promise or do I have to seek other ways? I'd prefer to stick with Promises to avoid having different code for a single use case. Alternatively, I would have to use jQuery for same functionality and I don't really know how.

Right now I'm solving this by force-loading of Promise polyfill from GitHub, but this doesn't feel right.

Comment: Can't you inject your script before the index.js execution ?

Comment: @dystroy Is that even possible to run a userscript before scripts of the page (those that are in <head> at least)? I'm already running it at document-start, I doubt I can do it earlier.

Comment: Force-loading a polyfill seems like the best option, you could try something like this `Promise = fetch('http:').constructor;`, but it's not going to work if the browser doesn't support `fetch()`.

Comment: @AlexeyLebedev that's actually a really clever trick you should post it as an answer.

Comment: Wow, their promise implementation is quite horrible.